# Cassandra List<UDT> not getting deserialized using datastax java driver 4.0.0

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am currently working on a new project and chose Cassandra as our data store.
I have a use case where I store prices for material and to accomplish it I created list of User-Defined Types (UDTs). But unfortunately, while deserialization using datastax driver. After queries for the required data, I found that the list object is null while in the database there is value for it. Is it a current limitation of Cassandra java driver or am I missing something?

This is how my simplified Entity (table) looks like:

```java
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "tenant_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private long tenantId;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "item_id", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String itemId;
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.LIST, userTypeName = "volume_scale_1")
    private List<VolumeScale> volumeScale1;
}
```

So I am getting volumeScale1 as null after database select query.

And this is how my UDT looks like:

1. In Cassandra database:

```
CREATE TYPE pricingservice.volume_scale (
    from_scale int,
    to_scale int,
    value frozen<price_value>
);
```

2. As UDT in java :

```java
@UserDefinedType("volume_scale")
public class VolumeScale
{  
   @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT, userTypeName = "from_scale")
   @Column("from_scale")
   private String fromScale;

   @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT, userTypeName = "to_scale")
   @Column("to_scale")
   private String toScale;
   @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UDT, userTypeName = "value")
   private PriceValue value;
   // getter and setter
}
```

I also tried using [Object Mapper from java driver itself](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/mapper/) as per @Alex suggestion but got stuck at one point where creating an object using ItemPriceByMaterialMapperBuilder is throwing compilation error. Is anything additional required towards annotation processing or am I missing something? do you have any idea how to use Mapper annotation? I used google AutoService also to achieve annotation processing externally but didn't work.

```java
    @Mapper
    //@AutoService(Processor.class)
    public interface ItemPriceByMaterialMapper
    // extends Processor
    {
        static MapperBuilder<ItemPriceByMaterialMapper> builder(CqlSession session) {
            return new ItemPriceByMaterialMapperBuilder(session);
          }

        @DaoFactory
        ItemPriceByMaterialDao itemPriceByMaterialDao ();

        // @DaoFactory
        // ItemPriceByMaterialDao itemPriceByMaterialDao(@DaoKeyspace CqlIdentifier
        // keyspace);
    }
```

Version used:

Java Version: 1.8

DataStax OSS java-driver-mapper-processor: 4.5.1

DataStax OSS java-driver-mapper-runtime: 4.5.1

Cassandra: 3.11.4

Spring Boot Framework: 2.2.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use object mapper and work with Spring Data Cassandra with Spring 2.2.6-RELEASE. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have multiple problems: if you're using Spring Data Cassandra, then you'll get older driver (3.7.2 for Spring 2.2.6-RELEASE), and it may clash with driver 4.0.0 (it's too old, don't use it) that you're trying to use.  Driver 4.x isn't binary compatible with previous drivers, and its support in Spring Data Cassandra *could be* only in the next major release of Spring.

Instead of Spring Data you can use [Object Mapper from java driver itself](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/mapper/) - it could be more optimized than Spring version.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Alex. I will try it.

Comment: Hi, Alex, I tried "Object Mapper from java driver itself" but got stuck at one point where one of the classes generated during annotation processing is InventoryMapperBuilder is not getting generated or I am missing something, do you have any idea. I used google AutoService also to achieve this.